# How to send the value in the slider made by javascript with a php

Tags: php, javascript

I use the jquery code made a slider in my website and i want to sent the value I get from the slider to my database with php. The jquery code sites address is right here. http://jqueryui.com/slider/#steps

My html form code:

```
<form action="like.php" method="post" id = "button">
<input type="hidden" name="likefemale" value = "<?php echo $rand_num_rows;?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="likemale" value = "<?php echo $rand_num_rows1;?>"/>
<input type = "hidden" name = "slider_val" id = "slider_val"/>
<input name="like" type="submit" value="like" />
</form>

<form action="unlike.php" method="post" id = "button1">
<input type="hidden" name="unlikefemale" value = "<?php echo $rand_num_rows; ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="unlikemale" value = "<?php echo $rand_num_rows1; ?>"/>
<input type = "hidden" name = "slider_val" id = "slider_val"/>
<input name="unlike" type="submit" value="unlike" />
</form>
```

I want the value sent by this two forms.

Comment: What happens when you try to implement that functionality in your code? Do you encounter errors or unexpected behavior? Will you share your code attempt with us so that we can provide specific assistance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your jqueryUI slider code, use `slide` event to get it's value. For example:

```
$("#yourSlider_1").slider({
    [...]
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#slider_val_1" ).val( ui.value );
    }
});
```

Also, use a different ID for the hidden inputs "slider_val" of your forms.